# SpringMVC lot loading resource files (JS and CSS)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following springMVC web app. This is the directory. I have all the css and js in the **vendor** folder:

[image]

This is my security configuration. I have tried adding "/resources/vendor/**" "/vendor/**" but nothing seems to work:

**SecurityConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.
                jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/resources/vendor/**", "/vendor/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/vendor/**","/favicon.ico");
    }

}
```

And webconfig. The resource path is configured:

**WebMvcConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

}
```

The resources are not loading. No 404 errors:

[image]

This is an example of the same files working:

[image]

The HTML header:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>TEST</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS-->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link href="css/sb-admin.css" >

</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put css and js inside `\src\main\resources\static`, so if you want to use vendor folder then it should be moved inside `static` folder.